# Javafx TableView change color cell when clicked

Tags: javafx, tableview, background-color, tablecell

I've made a tableview with javafx but i want to change the backgroundcolor of the cell that I clicked on. this is what i have now:

```
 tabel.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        tabel.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
        );
        tabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getClickCount() > 0) {
                    TablePosition cell =    tabel.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                    tabel.edit(cell.getRow(), cell.getTableColumn());
                    tabel.getSelectionModel().select(cell.getRow(), cell.getTableColumn());
                    System.out.println(cell.getRow()*scherm.getNumberOfColumns()+cell.getColumn());
                }
            }
        });
```

Now I just print the number of the cell but i also want to change the background color of that cell. 
Any ideas? if something in my code isn't clear, please ask.

Comment: Why do you involve the selection model and the focus model? Why do you set a click handler on a table rather than in a cell created in a cell factory?

Comment: What's the actual aim here? If it's just to change the background color of the focused cell, that is best done with CSS. Or is there something else you're actually trying to do? (Obviously you can't describe your entire project, but this looks like you are asking to fix a solution which is the wrong solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve. Some context would really help.)